# How to apply button style from code?

Tags: android

I have custom button style defined in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="buttonBlack">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_button_black_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

When I set it through layout xml, it works fine:

```
<Button style="@style/buttonBlack" ... />
```

When I set it through code, it does not work (I get empty button, no background):

```
Button button = new Button(this, null, R.style.buttonBlack);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_black_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_black_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_black_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Its works for me,can you post your selector file?

Comment: Robin, this is working for you??? What android version and sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ContextThemeWrapper`

```
Button button = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.buttonBlack));
```